# Heroku: Only the "/" is working on my php app

Tags: php, heroku, heroku-cli, fastroute

I use php **fast-route** to handle routing on my application on **Heroku** free web dyno. The application is not using any framework.

Only the / page works. The rest are not working. Though they work properly on my local server.

If I try to access the login page https://creationspace.herokuapp.com/login it return 404 error - page not Found.

Here is my Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Route.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
    return [
        ['GET', '/', ['App\Controllers\Homepage', 'show']],
        ['GET', '/login', ['App\Controllers\Account\Login', 'show']],
    ];
```

Please I need help.